# Font awesome not displaying in wordpress

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

Font awesome icons not displaying and they displaying square boxes instead of icons

I'm trying to prototype a marketing page and I'm using bootstrap and the new font awesome file. The problem is when I try to use an icon all that gets rendered on the page in a big square.

Comment: post some code, please.
what method do you use to include Font Awesome on your page? does your problem exist on all browsers?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your page cannot get/load the actual font-awesome font files.

Double check their locations to see if they are in the right place and that they are referenced correctly from your pages and your CSS.